# Send message with firebase to user with the phone number they have provided

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase for login and have enabled email authentication in android application.

In registration I am receiving phone number along with email and password. I want to send a message with a new password to my user's number when they click forgot password.

I can't figure out how to do this, so please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

FCM doesn't use an SMS service based on phone number but the device token instead which is generated on installation. You can implement this with FCM which requires Blaze plan enabled and Cloud Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

From there you can use dynamic links, or in-app routing to trigger cloud functions and password resets as you desire.

If you want to use the number to send an SMS, you will need to implement a 3rd party provider, I can recommend this guide that uses Vonage:
https://learn.vonage.com/blog/2020/01/24/send-and-receive-sms-messages-with-firebase-functions-dr/